# How to log messages issued by serilog in a nuget package in my ASP.NET Core app using ILogger

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, serilog, ilogger

This should be simple, but I cannot find an answer.

I have an ASP.NET Core (3.0) application. I use [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/)/`ILogger` for logging.

I am also using a library (Fishbus: [github](https://github.com/thonhotels/fishbus)/[nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FishBus/)) for interfacing with Azure Message Bus. The library logs suitable messages, but uses [Serilog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog/) to do it. So out of the box, no messages are logged.

How do I "connect" Serilog to the Microsoft logging framework so that I can see what the library is doing?

Comment: Well you need a logging provider/adapter. Most logging library should provide an logging addapter (which you add in your startup/program class, such as `loggerFactory.AddConsole().AddSerilog()`). If Seri log doesn't provide one, you gotta write your own adapter provider which pipes the messages from ilogger to your logger. See https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProvider.cs and https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLogger.cs for Console Logger implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, per se. You are beholden to what the library uses. `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` is a facade, so when you depend on that, the application can sub in an actual logging provider. However, when the library depends on the provider itself (i.e. Serilog), then there's no way to hook it into `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` or another provider.

That said, the same Serilog config can be used for both, if you also use the Serilog provider for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. They wouldn't be generating the logs in the same way, but they'd all end up in the same sink(s). Additionally, Serilog is somewhat of a facade itself, with its concept of sinks, so while you ultimately can't get rid of Serilog, you can configure different logging destinations via Serilog, instead of using different `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` providers.